# Error: Future resolved more than once

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Everything works fine when I run my angular app for the 1st time on the browser.However, I have gotten the below errors messages when I refreshed the page.

> /.../node_modules/fibers/future.js:248
>
> ```
>       throw new Error('Future resolved more than once');
>             ^
> Error: Future resolved more than once
>     at Object.Future.return (/.../node_modules/fibers/future.js:248:10)
>     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/.../server.js:38:34)
>     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:95:17)
>     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
>     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:92:17)
>     at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
>     at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
>     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
>     at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:128:10)
>     at HTTPParser.parserOnBody [as onBody] (http.js:143:22)
> ```

I have the following code in my server.js

```
var Fiber = require('fibers/future');  
var future = new Fiber;

function getNodeList(method){  
    ...  
    ...  
    ...  
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
        var nodesList;  
        if (res.statusCode === 200) {  
            res.on('data', function(d) {  
                // process.stdout.write(d);  
                if (Buffer.isBuffer(d)) {  
                    nodesList = JSON.parse(d.toString('utf-8'));  
                    future.return(nodesList); <---Error Happen Here 
                }  
            });  
        } else {  
            console.log("ERROR");  
        }  
    });  
}  
app.post('/viewNodeList', function(req, res) {  
    var object = getNodeList("GET");  
    console.log("this One!");  
    res.status(200).send(object);  
}.future());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `res` object is a [readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable), which can receive its data in multiple chunks, with each provided in a separate [`'data'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data).

You'll want to also listen for the [`'end'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end), which will only occur once at most per stream, to know when all of the chunks have been received.

```
    if (res.statusCode === 200) {  
        let chunks = [];
        let totalLength = 0;

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {  
            totalLength += chunk.length;
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });  

        res.on('end', function () {
            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks, totalLength);
            nodeList = JSON.parse(body.toString());
            future.return(nodesList);
        });
    } // ...
```

---

You'll also want to create a `new Future` for each use of `getNodeList()`.

```
var Fiber = require('fibers/future');

function getNodeList(method){
    var future = new Future;

    // ...
}
```

By creating it at the top of the script, only one `Future` will exist for every request. And, once it's set as completed by the first request, it can't be reused for others after that.

Comment: thanks @JonathanLonowski, it makes totally sense what you just said, I applied your suggestion but I still have the same error whenever I refresh the page. the error is still in this line `future.return(nodesList);` thanks again for your help! :-)